# Can a xib in a project use autolayout while the main storyboard doesn't?

Tags: ios, xcode5, autolayout, xib, uistoryboard

The subject says it all.

I would guess that the answer is "yes" since Xcode saves the xib and the storyboard independently. The question is, if this also works correctly while runtime or if there are known problems or quirks.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, auto layout can be turned on individually on any Interface Builder file. All the view controllers can coexist.